# node.js and a singleton that has an asynchronous call in getInstance

Tags: javascript, node.js, soap, asynchronous

I have a implemented a singleton following the model described in the book by Addy Osmani book, Learning Javascript design patterns.

This singleton is setting up a soap connection. This is an asynchronous call and I want to perform that in the getInstance call so the follow on calls can be guaranteed to have the connection that is completely up...

One thought i have is to pass in a callback to getInstance, make that call in my main.js function and by the time other scripts get to needing a connection, it will be up. And every other consumer of the soap connection, pass it null for the callback.

Is this a hack or a good way to do this?
If it is a not standard way of doing this, what do you suggest?

Comment: Some sample code will be nice.

Comment: my code is at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20061157/javascript-and-singleton-pattern

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When dealing with events, such as XMLHTTPRequest (be it SOAP or JSON) it's common to use a callback function.

However it's preferred to use Promises. Promises are designed to be adept at dealing with asynchronousness. The most notable advantage over callbacks is that Promises come with error handling, progression and cancellation built in.

Most popular frameworks and libraries include an implementation of Promises.

---

A minor note: a Singleton as a design pattern is, more often that not, an **anti-pattern**. Be very weary when using it, especially in the face of testability. I'm not familiar with Addy Osmani's work so I can't comment on this specific case.

The notion of a Singleton becomes moot when you apply good **Dependency Injection**.

Comment: Promises have nothing to do with modularity

Comment: You prefer to have all functions have 4 extra parameters for callbacks instead (done, fail, always, cancel)? Please elaborate.

Comment: Whether to have 4 parameters or 4 methods that accept callback is not about modularity at all, perhaps about readability. [I have written a lot about promises, like why one should use them.](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird#what-are-promises-and-why-should-i-use-them) +1 for the anti-pattern though.

Comment: I know this is an old post... but ... A Singleton is a proven and effective design pattern, NOT an anti-pattern! Can singletons bite you if you don’t employ strong design in your tests?  Yes, but that is from poor test design, not because there is something wrong with the Singleton Pattern. Dependency Injection and singletons are mutually exclusive things.  In no way does dependency injection remove the necessity of a singleton, and it is quite common to use a singleton when using dependency injection.

Comment: Also, you need to be careful saying things like "However it's preferred to use Promises."  There are significant performance degradations that can occur when using promises, especially Q.  Libraries like bluebird have greatly improved performance (and generators in node should make this comment obsolete), but callbacks, while potentially being nasty to deal with are still proven and fast!

Comment: When using DI you'll replace the singleton by a factory. A singleton is in essence it's own factory, so it's essential doing two things at once. If you're injecting the singleton you can still test it but you need to also mock the factory-part. Reference: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2094231/722762 (comment by saret)

Comment: I haven't worked with Q so I can't say anything about it's performance characteristics but in this use case, where only one Promise is expected the performance hit is negligible. There will always be a performance hit when you're working with abstractions. Worrying about performance at this stage is premature. The rule of thumb is: don't start optimizing until there is actually a problem.

Answer (score 1):

There are few ways of doing this:

1. Make you singleton an `EventEmitter`. Emit event `ready` or `initilized` when initialization completes. Problem: if a client starts listening after singleton is initialized, it will never catch `initialized` event. You can add `initialized` property and set it to true when initialization completes, to allow clients check object status. Still using it will require static check of the `.initialized` property, then setting listener or proceeding right away.

   1. Add callback to `getInstance`. If the object is initialized already, callback is called on next tick.
   2. Queue all requests before initialization is completed. It's super-convinient, but also complex to implement.

By the way, don't use `getInstance` in node.js, it's more like java-style. Just `module.exports = new MyClass` will do. In this case 2 method is not applicable as is, but you can ad a special method for just setting such a callback, like `onReady()`.

Comment: Event emitters are superb to handle flows even the application involves extensive flow of algorithm